# Netstat VS Netstat (Gnu/Linux VS BSD/Mac OS X)

Tags: linux, netstat, bsd

Why are there different versions of `netstat` for Gnu/Linux and BSD/Mac OS X?
I'm trying to get the latter to respond & behave more like the former.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that `ss` also seems to be incompatible with the latter. Possibly (a clue?) for similar reasons..

Comment: @JakeGould Thanks for posting the link. It's definitely related. Not quite the same question though.

Comment: That is already answered.  They share the same name and some functionality, but are other wise different because they were developed by different teams.  There isn't an underlying standard to adhere to, such as POSIX.  In fact, in linux distros, netstat and other net-tools are deprecated in favor of iproute2 (which contains `ss` you mention earlier).  They are different because they were created different.

Comment: My point is that there isn't going to be a satisfactory answer.  If you remove your assumption that they should behave the same way because they have the same name, then you'll see there isn't an answer.  The same applies to `find`, to `ps`, to `ifconfig` and countless other linux vs bsd commands.  They were developed by different groups with different goals without an underlying standard.

Comment: Perhaps [edit] your question?  I accept I might be misinterpreting the question, and more detail in the question itself may help anyone trying to answer.